# Custom Javascript audio html object can't get play() to work

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to create an audio object to use in certain parts of my code and can't figure out how I would attached play() method and pass audio file parameter.

See code below.

```
 var controllor = {
 mp3Directory:'folder/path/',
 myaudiofile: '',

   createAudio:function(myaudiofile){
     var myaudio = document.createElement('audioElement');
     myaudio = new Audio(this.mp3Directory + this.myaudiofile);
     return this;
   },

   playAudio:function(){
      createAudio.play();
   }
 }

controllor.createAudio();
controllor.playAudio(audio.mp3);
```

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off. Perhaps you should [brush up on OOP in JavaScript](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript--net-7670)?

Comment: @GabeRogan I think my syntax is slightly off because I'm trying to figure out how to play an audio file in my object and call the method.

Comment: If you want to make an Audio object, try `var player = new Audio()`